# Solve for opposite where angle = 30 degrees and Adjacent = 20 yards.

Tags: trigonometry

I have two known values, 
Adjacent = 20 yards
Angle = 30 degrees

I'm trying to solve for Opposite (x)

I think this is right, but Excel gives me an answer of 
tan(30) = x/20
x = 20(tan(30))
x = -128.107

I know X should be somewhere around 18 to 25 maybe?

-128.107 is way off. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $ tan(30) = \frac{Opposite}{20} \Rightarrow Opposite = 20 \cdot tan(30).$

What you've done is correct - try checking the units in which you are putting the input in Excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using excel. Excel doesn't work in degrees, but radians. Basically, they don't divide a circle into $360^\circ$, but rather $2\pi$. Since trigonometric functions really work on angle sizes, and not numbers, what unit you use to measure impacts the result greatly. Specifically, excel would say that $\sin(\pi) = 0$.

You need to use a calculator which uses degrees, or convert your degree measurements into radians. It's very possible that there is a setting for this somewhere inside excel that you can change that will fix everything. If not, then $30^\circ$ is one-twelfth of a whole circle, which in radians becomes $2\pi/12 = \pi/6\approx 0.5236$. Try using that instead of $30^\circ$, and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That makes complete sense now.  Thanks